# Setting variable without callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

How is it possible that script continues even without proper setting variable? Thanks for reply!

**Code**

```
function get(param) {

  // Connect to database and get the response ~ 1 sec
  db.get(param, function(output) {

    console.log("Hey, I set the variable!");

    return output;

  });

}

try {

  var username = get("username");
  var birthday = get("birthday");

} catch (e) {

  error = e;

}

if ( !error ) {

  console.log("No errors? Everything all right?");

}
```

**Output**

```
No errors? Everything all right?
Hey, I set the variable!
```

Comment: I think there's a bunch of code you're not showing us.

Comment: Where is that first block of code?  What does "few seconds later" mean ... how does that code get executed?  What does that "connect to database" comment mean?  What is the execution context for this code - is it in a browser or in some server-side system like Node.js? What does the code for the "get()" function **really** look like?

Comment: The thing is that I (and several other people) suspect what the problem is, but without seeing the real code to "get()" it's going to be very hard to say exactly what's going on.

Comment: @Pointy Okay, you are right. I added whole code. We're talking about Node.js (server-side javascript).

Comment: Where is the code for db.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking synchronously. What is happening is the two `get` statements are invoked but `db` has not yet invoked either callback. Your program continues merrily along checking for an `error` which is undefined as the catch block was never entered. As a consequence, "No errors..." is printed. Then `db` responds asynchronously to one of your `get` calls before exiting. The key thing here is you cannot assume the print statement is the result of `username` callback, it could be from `birthday`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know what database code that is, it's a sure bet that the function you pass in to `db.get()` cannot work the way your code seems to want. That function is a callback that won't be invoked until the database results are "ready" or something. You **cannot** have a "get()" routine that works the way yours does, in other words, because it cannot "wait" for the `db.get()` call.

You could rewrite your "get()" function to take its own function parameter.